# Apply full vim colorization for bash scripts that have no shebang line

Tags: linux, bash, vim, colors

So in my project there are many bash script files that are sourced, but never run directly, so they get no shebang line and no execute bit set.  Vim colors them a little bit, but doesn't use the full colorization.  How do I tweak vim to give me all the normal bash colors for these files?

EDIT:

Without shebang:

[image: Without shebang]

With shebang:

[image: With shebang]

EDIT 2:

There is an answer that works for file-by-file changes below, and I'll go with that if that's all I can get, but what I'd really like is to modify a config file or something else in my vim installation so that I always get the full "with shebang" colors even when there is no shebang.  There must be a file somewhere that defines the incomplete colorization, which I can just replace with the file defining the complete colorization.

EDIT 3:

The vim global variables set are not substantially different, as seen in these images (output of `:let g:`):

[Environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGs1D.jpg)

[Diffed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNUb0.png)

I'm sort of at a loss here.

EDIT 4:

I dumped the entire environment from a properly-colored window (left) and an improperly-colored window (right), and diffed them, finding this:

```
60 b:current_syntax       bash   |   61 b:current_syntax       conf
```

So, for some reason it thinks my shebangless source files are conf files.  So I need to figure out how to match them to bash instead.

Comment: `:syntax on` have you tried just turning on syntax highlighting? You could add this to your `.vimrc` to make it run every time you vi.

Comment: @MattClark Syntax highlighting is on.  What happens is, when I open a bash file with no shebang line at the top, I get incomplete colorization.  See my edit for images showing the issue.

Comment: What platform are you using?  Looks like windows; is it native, cygwin/mintty, or something else?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Crunchbang, which for most purposes is Debian.  The vim is 7.3, and my shell is terminator, with 256 color support enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `:setf sh`

You may want to place this at the top of the files (if you want no shebang):

```
# vim:ft=sh
```

Comment: Interestingly, `:setf bash` removes all color from the editor on my system, while `:setf sh` gives the desired colorization.  But I'm really wondering if there is a more permanent way to modify my vim install to use the `:setf sh` exclusively for all shell scripts?

Comment: The command "setf" cannot be in a modeline.  All modelines can do is set options. You want: `# vim:ft=bash`

Comment: There is no `bash` filetype. The filetype should be `sh`. If you need to tune the highlighting for bash, put `let g:is_bash = 1` in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Marked as answer, because I couldn't figure out how to make `filetype.vim` select `sh` instead of `conf` for shebangless shell script files.  Thanks!

Comment: So (of course) it was still a bit of a struggle ;)  Debian turns off modeline by default - running `:verbose set modeline?` will tell you what's going on with that.  Either remove the `set nomodeline` from `/usr/share/vim/vim73/debian.vim` or add `set modeline` to your own vimrc.  Then the above modeline will work.

Comment: It does not have to be on the top of the file, it can be put at the bottom (I believe that's a more common place).

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
let g:is_bash      = 1
```

in your `.vimrc`.  That sets the default filetype for unknown shell scripts to `bash`.  See full explanation in [:help ft-bash-syntax](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#ft-sh-syntax)

For those curious about the internals, at least on my Vim 7.4 install, `g:is_bash` is tested in an autocommand in `$VIM/vim74/filetype.vim`, which sets `b:is_bash` accordingly.  The syntax file `$VIM/vim74/syntax/sh.vim` then tests `b:is_bash` to decide how to highlight the file.

Comment: Didn't work.  I also tried adding it to `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/sh.vim`, but no dice there either.

Comment: In `/usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim` there is a function called `SetFileTypeSH` at line 1760, I think I may need to modify this but vimscript gives me headaches.

Comment: Would you be willing to try upgrading to Vim 7.4 (latest) and see if it helps?  I don't have a 7.3 install any more.

Comment: Well, sometime this year I need to upgrade the whole OS, which won't be fun since Crunchbang died.  I appreciate your help, but I'd rather not install a different vim just for this.

Comment: That's fair.  For what it's worth, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044378 suggests others have had problems.  https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory/vim/vim-7.3-sh_is_bash.patch is a patch to sh.vim that might help.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the links.  My syntax highlighting isn't broken per se, vim thinks my sourceable script files are type "conf" and applies a more minimal highlighting.  I'm sure I can get it from here, thanks!